# Account Recovery for Gmail failure

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

My private gmail account didnt recognize my password, answered all account recovery questions and it says it cannot recognize my account but i still have access to my email on my phone? I use this account for my business and need access. What can I do to get my account recovered?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you type in your password and security questions correctly.

If you forget your password and can't verify your account you'll need to contact Gmail support. In your query be sure to mention your phone account.